# Passing JSON value using jq command to a new JSON file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I ran curl command and then parsed the value ("id").

request:

```
curl "http://192.168.22.22/test/index/limit:1/page:1/sort:id/pag1.json" | jq -r '.[0].id'
```

curl response:

```
[
  {
    "id": "381",
    "org_id": "9",
    "date": "2018-10-10",
    "info": "THIS IS TEST",
    "uuid": "5bbd1b41bc",
    "published": 1,
    "an": "2",
    "attribute_count": "4",
    "orgc_id": "8",
    "timestamp": "1",
    "dEST": "0",
    "sharing": "0",
    "proposal": false,
    "locked": false,
    "level_id": "1",
    "publish_timestamp": "0",
    "disable_correlation": false,
    "extends_uuid": "",
    "Org": {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "test",
      "uuid": "5b9bc"
    },
    "Orgc": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "test",
      "uuid": "5b9f93bdeac1b41bc"
    },
    "ETag": []
  }
]
```

jq response:

```
381
```

Now I'm trying to get the "id" number 381, and then to create a new JSON file on the disk when I place the "id" number in the right place.

The new JSON file for example:

```
{
  "request": {
    "Event": {
      "id": "381",
      "task": "new"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide unparsed JSON output of `curl "http://192.168.22.22/test/index/limit:1/page:1/sort:id/pag1.json"` in your question.

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 1):

Given your input, this works:

```
jq -r '{"request": {"Event": {"id": .[0].id, "task": "new"}}}' > file
```

Comment: Got error:    jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index string with number

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   830  100   830    0     0  33200      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 33200
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index string with number